# postgres/sqlalchemy - how to add unique constraint to existing column of table

Tags: python, postgresql, flask-sqlalchemy, psycopg2, unique-constraint

I've looked at several other answers but have yet to find one that shows the create statement & the model class together, most just show how to define a column as unique when the table is created.

I have a working line of code that writes rows to postgres & the associated model class below

```
self.cur.execute("INSERT INTO autos(make,year,model,license) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)",(item['make'],item['year'],item['model'],item['license']))

class AutoItem(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'autos'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    make = db.Column(db.String(255))
    year = db.Column(db.String(255))
    model = db.Column(db.String(255))
    license = db.Column(db.String(255))
```

in order to prevent duplicate rows I added an `ON CONSTRAINT` statement to the line of code like so

```
self.cur.execute("INSERT INTO autos(make,year,model,license) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s) ON CONFLICT (license) DO NOTHING;",(item['make'],item['year'],item['model'],item['license']))
```

adding the `ON CONSTRAINT` statement generates the following error

```
psycopg2.errors.InvalidColumnReference: there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification
```

so to update the model class such that the license column is unique what I have now is

```
class AutoItem(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'autos'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    make = db.Column(db.String(255))
    year = db.Column(db.String(255))
    model = db.Column(db.String(255))
    license = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True) #THIS WORKS
```

and I added an import to the top of the model class (file name is models.py)

```
from sqlalchemy import UniqueConstraint #THIS WORKS
```

but the error `psycopg2.errors.InvalidColumnReference: there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification` still remains? Previously I dropped the table & created a new one but that generates the same error too. I don't know if its psycopg2, my model class and/or the `ON CONSTRAINT` statement that's the problem?

EDIT adding screenshot below

[image]

EDIT 2 - ISSUE IS RESOLVED

the working solution line of code and model class are above, see the update to the model class as well as the import at the top. I guess I made some mistake/s when creating the table. What worked for me was to completely drop the `autos` table & create it again...

Comment: If you look at the table within postgres, can you confirm the unique constraint is there?

Comment: hey @Doobeh thanks for reply, see my edit. As best I can tell the unique constraint is there. This screenshot was taken just by updating the model class as described above. I did NOT create this table in the terminal via `sudo -i -u postgres psql` & all relevant commands